# How to inspect an element in Chrome that only exists in DOM on Javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web-inspector

I know that chrome has a ":hover" state in the inspector for this, but it does not trigger the event.

As far as I can tell the markup that I want to inspect is written in the DOM after a jQuery `.hover()` event. And is immediatly removed from the DOM when my mouse leaves the element that is targeted by the `.hover()` event.

Is there any way to force this open, assuming I can't write in the Javascript files that hold the function that does this (but I can access the rest of the files and can read the unminified JS).

Comment: Chrome or any other browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Chrome developer tools tab "Sources", you have a roll out on the right labelled "Event Listener Breakpoints". Open stack "Mouse" and activate "mouseenter". The window/ javascript then gets "paused" when you hover an element while you can switch back to the "Elements" tab and inspect the dom.

Comment: Using the F8 key to jump from event to event is also useful. I wish there wasn't a dark overlay on top of the elements I'm inspecting, but this is awesome, I can do my work. Thank you.

Comment: as soon as you inspect elements the overlay disappears again